# How can I integrate Next Js with MDBootstrap

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mdbootstrap

Im learning Next Js with the official docs, so, Im trying to build a site and I'd love to integrate MDB.

I intstalled it as they recommend in here:
https://mdbootstrap.com/react/5-min-quick-start/

But when i run http://localhost:3000/ it throws the error as the screenshot below

[image: Error]

Can you help me?

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next.js#3-with-no-ssr

Answer (score 3):

It seems like mdb does not support SSR.

Every page in NextJS is first rendered from the server. If mdb accessed `window` or any browser only JS global (`history`, `localStorage`) in one render method, it will break SSR.

You do have some options though.

1. Use NextJS [dynamic components](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#3-with-no-ssr) to disable SSR
2. [Wait](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4381) for the NextJS team to implement a nice way to disable SSR for some components
3. Create a mock `window` object when doing SSR to avoid the error
4. Fork MDB to fix their components for SSR, and create a Pull Request to contribute your changes

Answer (score 0):

The `window` object does not exist on the server and is available only on the client side. 


In addition to what Clément Prévost has mentioned you can also load the desired components after `componentDidMount`. This is not the most efficient method.